# Redirect Specific Wildcard Subdomain to a specific url of another domain

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect specific wildcard subdomain to a specific url of another domain. the both domains are on the same server/public_html, and redirect all the inner pages of the wildcard subdomain to the inner pages of the other domain.

e.g

redirect `music.example.com` to `stackoverflow.com/music/`

and

redirect `music.example.com/happy-birthday/` to `stackoverflow.com/happy-birthday`

redirect `music.example.com/sing-to-you/` to `stackexchange.com/sing-to-you/`

I have more than 100k post so i cannot make the redirection of the inner pages one by one using .htaccess

Please help me out,

I tried the below code

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(music.example.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^()$ https://www.stackoverflow.com/music/ [R=301,L]`

but it only redirect the homepage to the specific url which I wanted, but the rest of the urls is the main issue, If I use the normal domain redirection, it works for the rest of the urls, but the function of the code above will stop working

Here is the below code for normal domain redirect redirection

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^music\.domain.com\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://wwww.stackoverflow.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]`

Comment: We can help but first please post what you have tried in order to redirect your urls.

Comment: Here is what I have tried out, but I could not achieve my aim 
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(music.example.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^()$ https://www.stackoverflow.com/music/ [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the below htaccess code and it works perfectly.

```
RewriteEngine On

# "music.example.com/" to "another.example/music/"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^music\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://another.example/music/ [R=302,L]

# "music.example.com/<something>" to "another.example/<something>"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^music\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) https://another.example/$1 [R=302,L]
```

The `RewriteCond` (condition) directive checks the requested host. The `RewriteRule` naturally redirects to the other domain. In the second rule the URL-path from the request is captured in the `$1` backreference.